# Button does nothing?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have this little form, where you should type in your birth year. After that you should press a button, and it should automatically find out if you are over 18, through your birth year. The problem is that when you press the button, nothing happens. Even if you leave it blank it still does nothing, even though the code says it should come with an error.

This is my code:

```
   <div align="center">    

  <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE[ "usermobile"])) { ?>    

  <ul>
    <li><a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>    

  <!--DEMO03-->
  <div id="modal-03" style="background-image:url(images/access.jpg); background-size:cover;">
    <!--"THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID-->
    <div id="btn-close-modal" class="close-modal-03">
      <!--CLOSE MODAL-->
    </div>

    <div class="modal-content">
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <img src="images/logo.png" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <font color="#bfbaa8">Man skal være over 18 år, for at få adgang til denne side.<br />
                <font size="+4">Indtast dit fødselsår</font>
      <br />
      <input maxlength="4" id="age_validation_input" size="33" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(191, 186, 168, 0.8); border:none; height:90px; width:380px; color:#3d3b33; padding:15px; font-size:70px; font-weight:bold;" value="F.eks. 1963" onblur="onBlur(this);"
      onfocus="onFocus(this);">
      </font>
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="age_validation_btn" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(99, 95, 82, 0.8); border:none; height:65px; width:410px; color:#c4bda4; font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;" value="OK her" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <font size="-1" color="#69665b">Ved at klikke "OK" giver du tilladelse til, at webstedet benytter cookies.</font>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>    

</div>


<script>
  $('#age_validation_btn').on('click', function() {

    var age = parseInt($('#age_validation_input').val(), 10);
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    var calculatedYear = currentYear - 123;
    var oldage = age - calculatedYear;

    if (age > currentYear) {
      swal("Hov!", "Vi er ikke nået til det år endnu.", "error");
      return false;
    }

    if (oldage < 5) {
      swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste et gyldigt fødselsår.", "error");
      return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(age) || age == 'F.eks. 1963') {
      swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste dit fødselsår, for at få adgang til denne side.", "error");
      return false; //stop the validation here
    }

    if (new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) {
      Cookies.set("usermobile", "ok", {
        expires: 1
      });
      $('#btn-close-modal').trigger('click');
    } else {
      Cookies.remove("usermobile");
      location.href = 'noaccess.html';
    }
  });
</script>

<script>
  document.getElementById('age_validation_input').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (!([8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
      (key == 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
      (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
      (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
    )) e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/animatedModal.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //demo 03
  $("#demo03").animatedModal({
    modalTarget: 'modal-03',
    animatedIn: 'bounceInDown',
    animatedOut: 'bounceOutUp',
    color: '#434138',
    // Callbacks
    beforeOpen: function() {
      console.log("The animation was called");
    },
    afterOpen: function() {
      console.log("The animation is completed");
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
      console.log("The animation was called");
    },
    afterClose: function() {
      console.log("The animation is completed");
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('demo03');
    link.click();
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Try a `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`

Comment: There is some jQuery to handle the button `age_validation_btn`, have you looked at the browser's console to see if there are errors?

Comment: How do I look at the console?

Comment: F12 in any browser will open the console

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery code before jQuery has been loaded.  The `script` tag which references jQuery itself has to come *before* any `script` tag which tries to use that reference.

Comment: This is what I get: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
(anonym funktion)index.php:175

Comment: I just moved the scripts up as you said @David and it worked! Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the JQuery library before you use it. Also if you would have Pressed `F12` to open the console, where there should be an error telling you that the library is missing.

This should work :

```
<div align="center">


<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["usermobile"])) { ?>


    <ul>
            <li><a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03 7</a></li>
        </ul>




                <!--DEMO03-->
      <div id="modal-03" style="background-image:url(images/access.jpg); background-size:cover;">
            <!--"THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID-->
        <div  id="btn-close-modal" class="close-modal-03"> 
                <!--CLOSE MODAL-->
            </div>

            <div class="modal-content">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
            <br /><br />
                <font color="#bfbaa8">Man skal være over 18 år, for at få adgang til denne side.<br />
                <font size="+4">Indtast dit fødselsår</font><br />
                <input maxlength="4" id="age_validation_input" size="33" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(191, 186, 168, 0.8); border:none; height:90px; width:380px; color:#3d3b33; padding:15px; font-size:70px; font-weight:bold;" value="F.eks. 1963" onblur="onBlur(this);" onfocus="onFocus(this);"></font>
 <br />
<input type="button" id="age_validation_btn" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(99, 95, 82, 0.8); border:none; height:65px; width:410px; color:#c4bda4; font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;" value="OK her" />
<br /><br />
<font size="-1" color="#69665b">Ved at klikke "OK" giver du tilladelse til, at webstedet benytter cookies.</font>
            </div>
        </div>



<?php } ?>




</div>




<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/animatedModal.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $('#age_validation_btn').on('click', function() {

    var age = parseInt($('#age_validation_input').val(), 10);
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    var calculatedYear = currentYear - 123;
    var oldage = age - calculatedYear;

    if(age > currentYear) {
        swal("Hov!", "Vi er ikke nået til det år endnu.", "error");
        return false;
    }

    if(oldage < 5) {
        swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste et gyldigt fødselsår.", "error");
        return false;
    }

    if(isNaN(age) || age == 'F.eks. 1963') {
        swal("Hov!", "Du skal indtaste dit fødselsår, for at få adgang til denne side.", "error");
        return false;//stop the validation here
    }

    if (new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) { 
    Cookies.set("usermobile", "ok", { expires: 1 });
     $('#btn-close-modal').trigger('click');
    } else {
     Cookies.remove("usermobile");
    location.href = 'noaccess.html';
    }
});


  </script>

  <script>
  document.getElementById('age_validation_input').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var key   = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (!( [8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
         (key == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey  ) ) || 
         (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
         (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
         (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
       )) e.preventDefault();
});
  </script>

        <script>


            //demo 03
            $("#demo03").animatedModal({
                modalTarget:'modal-03',
                animatedIn:'bounceInDown',
                animatedOut:'bounceOutUp',
                color:'#434138',
                // Callbacks
                beforeOpen: function() {
                    console.log("The animation was called");
                },           
                afterOpen: function() {
                    console.log("The animation is completed");
                }, 
                beforeClose: function() {
                    console.log("The animation was called");
                }, 
                afterClose: function() {
                    console.log("The animation is completed");
                }
            });


        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var link = document.getElementById('demo03');
                link.click();
            })();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your jquery file before all your other javascript code. Otherwise it will try to run your code before Jquery is loaded, and it will fail.

Also try to put your self a document ready function to make sure it will only run when the page is fully loaded like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // yourcode
}
```